# primefaces selectOneMenu not working in Dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this dialog:

[image]

The code for this dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Détails du produit" showEffect="fade" modal="true"
    widgetVar="manageProductDialog" responsive="true">
    <p:outputPanel id="manage-product-content" class="ui-fluid">
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty productMB.selectedProduct}">
            <p:graphicImage
                name="images/product/#{productMB.selectedProduct.img}"
                library="demo" styleClass="product-image"
                rendered="#{not empty productMB.selectedProduct.img}" />
            <div class="p-field">
                <p:outputLabel for="name">Nom</p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{productMB.selectedProduct.name}"
                    required="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-field">
                <p:outputLabel for="category">Catégorie</p:outputLabel>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="category"
                    value="#{productMB.selectedProduct.category}"
                    layout="responsive">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{categoryMB.categories}" var="cat" itemValue="#{cat}" itemLabel="#{cat.name}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
            <div class="p-formgrid p-grid">
                <div class="p-field p-col">
                    <p:outputLabel for="price">Prix</p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputNumber id="price"
                        value="#{productMB.selectedProduct.price}" symbol=" DH"
                        symbolPosition="s" decimalSeparator="." thousandSeparator="," />
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Enregister" icon="pi pi-check"
            actionListener="#{productMB.saveProduct}"
            update="manage-product-content"
            process="manage-product-content @this" />
        <p:commandButton value="Annuler" icon="pi pi-times"
            onclick="PF('manageProductDialog').hide()"
            class="ui-button-secondary" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dialog>
```

The problem I have is that when I click on `Enregister` button the `p:selectOneMenu` is not validated even that a value was selected.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Which validation isn't fired? I can see only the required field. Are you sure you don't need a converter for that field?

Comment: I think you are missing a converter for the SelectOne that is why its failing .See the Advanced example here for converter usage: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml